Ошибка при загрузке Ubuntu на виртуальную машину Virtual Box на macOS
Пытаюсь установить Ubuntu на Virtual box на mac.
При попытке запуска выскакивает консоль Shell

По гайдам из интернета пытался активировать FS0:\efi\boot\grubx64.efi
Но возникает ошибка: "Command Error Status: Unsupported"

Я просто без понятия что не так! помогите пожалуйста новичку!

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Какой мак? Какая версия виртуалбокса?

@andreymal MacBook air 13, Virtual box самый новый 7.1.4 (macOS / Apple Silicon hosts)

«Apple Silicon» — вот, а вы пытаетесь запустить убунту, которая не для Apple Silicon (то есть не ARM)

(но это не точно, меня смущает значок черепашки)

@andreymal А что он значит?
